# Notify when connected to working Wi-Fi point

Tags: wi-fi, notifications, sip

I use my phone to receive all my calls over SIP.  Sometimes when I need to make a call I'm not around a (working) access point.

Let's say, if I'm walking around is there an app that can notify me (via vibrate or ringtone) when I've connected to an access point? So basically whenever SIPdroid lights up green.

Comment: "Notify when open WiFi access point is found" is available in stock Android. Is this not what you're talking about?

Comment: You could probably user Tasker to create your own alert too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick Marketplace search for *WiFi Notify* resulted in the following:

[WifiNotify](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifinotify/fr.bstevant.android.WifiNotify)

[image: WifiNotify QR Code]